# Code returns only 1 json object to the listview

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I have 3 objects in my jsonarray, but when I execute this code only 1 jsonobject is added in the listview. My code is working but it only returns 1 jsonobject.

Here is my code:

```
String jsonString = s;
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);

if (array != null && array.length() > 0) {

  //It will evalvate each json object.
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    if (array.get(i) instanceof JSONObject) {
      JSONObject receivedObject = array.optJSONObject(i);
      System.out.println("---Received Object---" + receivedObject);
      if (receivedObject != null) {
        //for userid fetch
        String userID = receivedObject.getString("userid");
        System.out.println("---User ID---" + userID);
      }
    } else if (array.get(i) instanceof JSONArray) {
      JSONArray innerArray = array.optJSONArray(i);
      for (int j = 0; j < innerArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject receivedObject = innerArray.getJSONObject(j);
        //     System.out.println("---Received Inner Array Object---"+receivedObject);
        if (receivedObject != null) {
          //for userid fetch

          String idnumber = receivedObject.getString("idclearance");
          // System.out.println("---User ID---"+userID);
          String firstname = receivedObject.getString("firstname");
          String lastname = receivedObject.getString("lastname");
          String datetime = receivedObject.getString("datetime");
          String purpose = receivedObject.getString("purpose");

          //   System.out.println(firstname + lastname + idnumber +datetime);

          if (documentlist.contains("Clearance Control #:" + idnumber + ", " + "Name:" + firstname + " " + lastname + ", " + "Purpose:" + purpose + ", " + "Date Requested:" + datetime + " -->" + "APPLICATION FORM")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The information is already displayed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          } else {

            documentlist.add("Clearance Control #:" + idnumber + ", " + "Name:" + firstname + " " + lastname + ", " + "Purpose:" + purpose + ", " + "Date Requested:" + datetime + " -->" + "APPLICATION FORM");
            documentlist.remove("No document selected");


          }

        }

      }
    }
  }
}
}

arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Not clear, Can you please post json response.

Comment: [[{"idclearance":"2009","userid":"519","firstname":"Renz Francis","lastname":"Castaloni","datetime":"2018-02-04","purpose":"Postal ID"}]][[{"idclearance":"2009","userid":"519","firstname":"Renz Francis","lastname":"Castaloni","datetime":"2018-02-04","purpose":"Postal ID"}],[{"idclearance":"2009","userid":"519","firstname":"Renz Francis","lastname":"Castaloni","datetime":"2018-02-04","purpose":"Postal ID"},{"idclearance":"2010","userid":"519","firstname":"Renz Francis","lastname":"Castaloni","datetime":"2018-02-04","purpose":"Residency"}]]

Comment: i want to return all of the object to listview

Comment: This json is not a valid JsonArray

Comment: but it return 1 json object in my listview

Comment: it should be [
  {
    "idclearance": "2009",
    "userid": "519",
    "firstname": "Renz Francis",
    "lastname": "Castaloni",
    "datetime": "2018-02-04",
    "purpose": "Postal ID"
  },
  {
    "idclearance": "2009",
    "userid": "519",
    "firstname": "Renz Francis",
    "lastname": "Castaloni",
    "datetime": "2018-02-04",
    "purpose": "Postal ID"
  }]

Comment: please check https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

Comment: why it return 1 json object? :( i dont understand.

Comment: Json is invalid. you can check it here http://json.parser.online.fr validate here

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the jsonArray is valid. it has unnecessary square brackets. Please validate your json string. is this something that you have created or are you getting this from an API call ?

Comment: im getting this from API call

Comment: The loop will stop when it encounters "]". that is why you are getting the loop to go just once.

Comment: <?php
 $hn='localhost';
  $db='barangay';
  $un='barangay';
  $pw='barangay';
$userid=$_POST['userid'];
$conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clearancerequest WHERE userid='$userid'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
    
 
 $json = json_encode($data);
 
 echo $json;
 }
} else {
 echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

Comment: Can you put all the necessary code snippets including a json example of what your android code tries to parse in the first message